# How to display Bootstrap button group in RTL pages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the Bootstrap button group on an right to left (RTL) page.

However, the buttons are flipped. The curved edges are not in the outer edges of the group, but next to the middle button.

I am using the code referenced here: [Buttons Group. Basic Example.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups-single)

the result is this:
[image]

I added an inline style to the main div tag in the bootstrap code, but it did not change anything:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" style="direction:rtl;" role="group" aria-label="...">
```

So my question is: how to style the buttons in a way that shows correctly on RTL pages?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

It seems that all Bootstrap buttons have problem with RTL for me.
I tried a different type :Split button dropdowns using the code [in this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)
and this is the result:
[image]

Although it is showing like this in the Bootstrap Documentation:
[image]

I tried adding `direction:rtl`, but again, it did not make any difference.

Comment: A demo would be useful

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to setup a demo environment for RTL on stackoverflow. can you please guide me? thanks.

Comment: Try a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that shows the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot. I added the snippet and it is running.

Comment: Is it showing the problem, because it's not for me?

Comment: I suspect though that these radii are assumed by DOM position which isn't effected by `direction`. You'd probably have to override the default CSS based on a new class applied to the group.

Comment: In the snippet I can't show the error. I tied t override the code by adding `direction:rtl`to the main div, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Pauline_D, I found out that it is not related to this type of buttons only. please check the post edit with the new findings i added now. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I changed three bootstrap classes;
first:

```
.btn-group > .btn,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn {
  position: relative;
  float: left; // => right
}
```

second:

```
.btn-group > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
border-top-right-radius: 0; //change right to left
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0; //change right to left
}
```

and last:

```
.btn-group > .btn:last-child:not(:first-child),
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0; // change left to right
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; // change left to right
}
```